# What is necessary to know before seeing The Avengers 2?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

Imagine you completely ignored the previous movies of Marvel Cinematic Universe but you suddenly want to see The Avengers 2:Age of Ultron that was recently released. You also never read comic books in your life.

What are the necessary informations you need to know before going to see the movie? For example, is watching The Avengers an absolute necessity? Or knowing that a team of super heroes had been active before enough to enjoy the new movie?

Comment: This is a reasonable question, why the downvote?

Comment: It's not a good question, and it borders on off-topic (primarily opinion based).

Comment: This differs from person to person. Some people take these movies very casually, some take it pretty seriously. You can't have a one-size-fits-all answer to this.

Comment: It's not opinion based. For example before watching a later movie about superhero X, you would probably benefit from seeing the origin movie. Thor has such a movie, Iron Man does, Captain America does, Black Widow doesn't, etc etc.

Comment: Do you need to know who the Hulk is before seeing a movie where there is this guy who becomes him? Is it explained in Avengers 2? Etc etc.

Comment: @phantom42 I think perhaps this is just poorly worded.  There are already similar questions that have received plenty of upvotes and good answers.  Like [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/is-there-an-official-marvel-cinematic-universe-viewing-order) and [this other one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34975/should-i-watch-the-avengers-before-going-to-see-iron-man-3).

Comment: The problem is that what you and I feel are necessary to know, or are sufficiently explained in this movie or that movie is a difference of opinion. There's also an issue of what sort of things you care about at all. It may not be referenced in *AoU* that Natasha was once secretly spying on Tony Stark as his assistant, but maybe I feel it makes a difference in the dynamic of their relationship.

Comment: We also already have [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85736/5184) (ignore the OP's misunderstanding of the word "foreshadow"), which is related.

Comment: We have a similar question for the first *Avengers* film, except it's asking which films are necessary to watch prior to seeing *Avengers*.  If this was edited into a [tag:suggested-order] style question, it'd be on topic.

Comment: 1. Cinema popcorn is very over-priced. Try to sneak your own snacks in. 2. The events of the film are not based on real events. Any similarity to any persons, living or dead, is entirely coincidental. 3. No, you can’t have Scarlett Johansson. She’s promised to me. 4. When a character dies in a film, the person playing them doesn’t really die, so don’t worry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Official policy is that you don't need to have seen any other part of the MCU to enjoy *Age of Ultron*, except possibly for *The Avengers*. In [an interview with  AlloCiné](http://www.allocine.fr/article/fichearticle_gen_carticle=18630302.html), Whedon commented on this:

> "I have to make my movie assuming that people will only have seen the first one, or possibly not even seen the first one. I can't assume that everybody went to see *Thor [The Dark World]*, *Captain America [The Winter Soldier]*, and *Iron Man [3]* in-between. I have to go from one movie to the next and be true to what's happened, but not be slavish to it... The model I'm always trying to build from, my guiding star, is *The Godfather Part II* where a ton has happened in-between and it's a very different movie [from *The Godfather*], but you don't need any information: it's there in the film."

In theory, watch *The Avengers* and you'll be good to go. You may not get the complete experience without having seen the [other dozen MCU movies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films), but you *shouldn't* miss any of the important elements of the story.

Now that I've finally seen the movie, I confirm that Whedon was telling the truth. The main plot is perfectly comprehensible without having seen any other MCU movies. Having seen *The Avengers* is sufficient to introduce you to most returning characters (the Avengers themselves, Maria Hill, Fury, Erik Selvig) and to Loki's scepter.

There are a few passing references to events from other MCU movies, and references to the Infinity Stones, that won't make sense unless you've seen other movies:

- James Rhodes (War Machine) and Sam Wilson (Falcon) each have brief appearances. They were introduced respectively in *Iron Man* (and in *Iron Man* 3 as War Machine) and *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*
- The major plot twist from *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* and season 1 of *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* is referenced.

  > This event being the fall of S.H.I.E.L.D. The fact that character have a hard time seeing the difference between S.H.I.E.L.D. and Hydra is referenced at least once
- Thor remarks that four of the Infinity Stones have emerged in the last four years, and they are shown in a montage. The Tesseract and Loki's Sceptre both featured prominently in *The Avengers*, although the Tesseract was introduced in *Captain America*, but the other two are from *Thor: The Dark World* and *Guardians of the Galaxy*. Keen covered the Infinity Stones in [his answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64573/which-infinity-stones-have-we-seen-so-far-in-the-marvel-cinematic-universe) (No spoiler tags in use there, so be careful if you care about that sort of thing)

Comment: "We won't know until it comes out." It's out now in some countries.

Comment: @phantom42 I just removed that bit entirely; too opinion-y. I guess the big debate now is going to be if Whedon lived up to his promise

Answer (score -3):

I'ld recommend catching up, by watching all the previous films in order of their release dates. OR or or skip 'age of ultron' and so keep a perfect record - of missing some of the best films ever made!!!.

Comment: And why would this imaginary self you refer to, having ignored all of Marvel All,even be aware or care about AOU??

Comment: _best films ever made_... Are you serious? Have you actually watched them??

Comment: Serious and have watched them many times. They have not disappointed much, and are entertaining, so say many devotees. If you don't like them, what are you critics doing here or watching more than one or two?

Comment: The sad part is you've probably never even seen Die Hard...

Comment: I have seen all the Die Hard films, what's your point? There is hardly a film I haven't seen, made in the last 80 years, except for the Twilight series. Your perspective is the sadness inducing factor.